# UseRuntimeConfig not found in NUXT 3

Tags: environment-variables, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nrwl-nx, pinia

According to [NUXT docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config) I need to use runtimeConfig inside defineNuxtConfig to set and get environmentvariables.

However when trying to follow this I get an error, saying useRuntimeConfig is not defined. What could be the problem here? I'm using NUXT inside a NX monorepo.

edit: this seems to be an issue with NX monorepo and @nx/nuxt. Example repo: https://github.com/simongussenhoven/runtimeConfig

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@nx/source",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nx run-many --target=serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "start": "nx start",
    "lint": "nx lint",
    "test": "nx test",
    "e2e": "nx e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "1.0.0",
    "@nuxt/eslint-config": "0.2.0",
    "@nuxt/kit": "^3.10.0",
    "@nuxt/ui-templates": "^1.3.1",
    "@nx/eslint": "18.0.4",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "18.0.4",
    "@nx/js": "18.0.4",
    "@nx/nuxt": "18.0.4",
    "@nx/vite": "18.0.4",
    "@nx/web": "18.0.4",
    "@nx/workspace": "18.0.4",
    "@swc-node/register": "~1.8.0",
    "@swc/core": "~1.3.85",
    "@swc/helpers": "~0.5.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.13.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.13.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
    "@vitest/coverage-v8": "^1.0.4",
    "@vitest/ui": "^1.0.4",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.1",
    "eslint": "~8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "h3": "^1.8.2",
    "jsdom": "~22.1.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.10.0",
    "nx": "18.0.4",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "sass": "1.62.1",
    "typescript": "~5.3.2",
    "vite": "~5.0.0",
    "vitest": "^1.0.4",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.4",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.8"
  }
}
```

I've tried a clean install, updating typescript but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

this is a runtimeConfig working example for your `nuxt.config.ts` file:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    // The private keys which are only available within server-side
    secretConfig: 'foo',
    // You can set runtimeConfig variables from process.env
    fromEnv: process.env.YOUR_ENV_VAR,
    // Keys within public, will be also exposed to the client-side
    public: {
      apiBase: '/api'
    }
  }
})
```

If you are using node `v20` or newer you can pass env files into your commands like this:

```
node --env-file=.env script.js
```

But if you are using old node versions you can read env vars using `dot-env` package https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: Thanks @thebyteland, this indeed works in a normal nuxt project just fine. I guess this has to do with nx and nx/nuxt. I've updated the question.

Comment: Apparently, NX disables the autoImport var in nuxt.config.ts:

  imports: {
    autoImport: false,
  },

Setting this to true still breaks the app, since Nitro won't finish the build, but I can log config when pasting this in the script of app.vue AFTER the app has started.

const config = useRuntimeConfig();
  return config

It doesn't solve the problem but I guess it's progress.

Comment: ¿Where are you calling the useRuntimeConfig composable? If u can not autoimport composables you can import them manually. I could help you  better if you share your useRuntimeConfig implementation.